# How to get the salesforce object field details by clicking a button and displayed in a form?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

How to get the salesforce object field details by clicking a button and displayed in a form?

### my component :

```
<aura:component controller="RPAProcess" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

      <aura:attribute name="CustomerName" type="String" default="" />
      <aura:attribute name="PhoneNumber" type="String" default="" /><br/>

     <div>   
       <lightning:input label="Customer Name" name="customername" value="{!v.CustomerName}" />
        <br/>
        <lightning:input label="Phone Number" name="phonenumber" value="{!v.PhoneNumber}" />
        <br/>

        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Get Data" onclick="{!c.getData}" />
    </div>
```

### Controller :

```
({
    getData : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getDetails");        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){           
          console.log(':::'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));           
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

### Apex class:

```
public class RPAProcess {

    @auraEnabled
    public static List<RPABot__c> getDetails(){
    return [ SELECT Id, Customer_Name__c,DOB__c,RPA_ID__c,Pin__c,Phone_Number__c FROM RPABot__c];

  }
}
```

Please help me how to get the details by clicking a button and displayed in a form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Controller code should be written like this

```
({
    getData : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getDetails");        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){           
          console.log(':::'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue())); 
          **component.set("v.CustomerName",response.getReturnValue().Customer_Name__c);
          component.set("v.PhoneNumber",response.getReturnValue().Phone_Number__c);**
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})


Apex Class

public class RPAProcess {

    @auraEnabled
    public static RPABot__c getDetails(){
    return [ SELECT Id, Customer_Name__c,DOB__c,RPA_ID__c,Pin__c,Phone_Number__c FROM RPABot__c Limit 1];

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please (1) do not ask for upvotes in your posts; (2) make sure to use the `{}` tool to format your code in the editor; (3) please include *explanation* in your post, not just a code dump. See [answer] for more.